# What state is used by a triggered inner function when dependant on differing value of outer function

Tags: javascript

1) I have an inner function that is event driven.
2) The inner function depends on variables in the outer function.
3) The variables in the outer functions are parameters to the outer function.
4) The outer function is being runned several times.

q) What values can I excepct the parameter variables from the outer function to have when the inner function gets triggered later on in the code?

scenario 1) When triggering the inner function, the exact state of the outer function that existed when creating the inner function is used.
scenario 2) When triggering the inner function, the latest value from the outer functions is used.

example:

```
function outerFunction(parameter) {
    var object = new Object();
    object.on('click', function () {
        alert(parameter);
    });
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time `outerFunction` is called, a new event listener is registered for clicks on `object`. So, if you call:

```
outerFunction('foo');
outerFunction('bar');
```

you should see two alerts, one for `'foo'`, and one for `'bar'`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of jQuery (and, probably, similar libraries) each time you call on(evt, handler) you bind new handler to element for that event. And jQuery stacks handlers.

So if you do:

```
outerFunction(1);
outerFunction(2);
```

jQuery will bind two handlers, and when triggering 'click' on your object you will get, in sequence:

1. Alert for "1".
2. Alert for "2".

Fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/ajWvk/

If it is your implementation of some abstract event-binding, and your implementation doesn't stack handlers, you will just bind new handler on each invocation of outerFunction, erasing all previous handlers.

In this case, calling:

```
outerFunction(1);
outerFunction(2);
```

will only alert "2", when "click" is triggered on object.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `parameter` is.  In javascript, strings and numbers are passed by value but objects are passed by reference.  So if `parameter` is a string then it will work like bfavaretto said.  However, if `parameter` is an object and you alert on `parameter.text`, then you will be alerted with whatever the current value of `parameter.text` is.

Try defining these in the console:

```
function outerFunction(parameter) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(parameter);
    },5000);
}

function otherOuterFunction(parameter) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(parameter.text);
    },5000);
}
```

Now, when you run this line it will log "test":

```
parameter = "text"; outerFunction(parameter); parameter = "hi";
```

But this will log "hi":

```
obj = {text: "text"}; otherOuterFunction(obj); obj.text = "hi";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I would like to clarify the following: <br />Say that the object returned by the function gets printed in HTML  page and we get many different objects. Will object runned in sequence 3 return 3 and object runned in sequence 10 return 10?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, could you post an example of what you mean?